# run onclick function of a element with jquery by the id element

Tags: jquery, html

Can I run onclick function of a 'a' element by id?

```
<a id="id_12" onclick="myfunction('1')">text</a>
<a id="id_23" onclick="myfunction('2')">text</a>
<a id="id_34" onclick="myfunction('3')">text</a>
<a id="id_45" onclick="myfunction('4')">text</a>
```

when users press enter key I know id of "a" element and I would like run relative function into onclick. It's possible??

Thanks.

Comment: Show the code where you find the ID of the anchor on pressing enter.

Comment: one short question, is your link list generated dynamically ?

Answer (score 1):

You could try this to help compact and visually control your function actions under on click method, all from one place on your page...

The HTML...

```
<div id="mlinks">
<a id="id_12">text</a>
<a id="id_13">text</a>
...
...
</div>
```

The JS...

```
$(function() {
  $('#mlinks').find('a').on("click",function(event) {
  mthis = $(this);
  var mid = mthis.attr('id');

  if (mid == "id_12") {
   console.log('you found 12');
   //and do stuff or adjust a variable value...
  }

  if (mid == "id_13") {
   console.log('you found 13');
   //and do other stuff or adjust a variable value again...
  }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
$('#id_12')[0].onclick();
```

Or without the HTML `onclick` event, with jQuery only:

```
<a id="id_12">text</a>
```

Then

```
// Bind an event handler to the "click" JavaScript event
$('#id_12').click(myFunction('1'));

// Execute the handler
$('#id_12').trigger('click');
```

But i didn't understand how you know the id of `<a>` when your users press <kbd>ENTER</kbd> ?

Comment: Because when user press up or down key I change an 'i' javascript counter, that is number of id (id="id_i"). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery we have to use either 'trigger' or simply click function alone or with an anonymous function as an argument.

Example -

```
 - $('id').click();
 - $('id').click(function() { myfunction('1'); //your statements  });
 - $('id').trigger('click');
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I think that third item is correct, but not work. Very Thanks.

Comment: the first and the third are the same, the second is binding an event to click event , is different.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `on()` binding handler

```
$('#yourid').on('click' , function() { lot of stuff... });
```